# How to copy a SQL Server 2005 database from local to the server

Tags: sql-server-2005

I want to export database from local computer to database server in SQL Server 2005.

How can I restore database without having access to file system of database server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SQL Server's built-in backup and restore functions.
Make a backup of your local database, and write it on some network share (can be anywhere in the network, doesn't have to be on the database server):

```
BACKUP DATABASE MyDatabase TO DISK = '\\Servername\Share\MyBackup.bak'
```

Then, you can restore the database on the database server, reading the backup directly from the network share:

```
RESTORE DATABASE MyDatabase FROM DISK = '\\Servername\Share\MyBackup.bak'
```

Note that you have to everything in T-SQL to be able to read and write directly to network shares!
(You can also backup  and restore databases from the GUI in SQL Server Management Studio, but you can only use local folders there)

Answer (score 1):

Your situation is, you want to copy the database from your local to remote database server but you do have access to the remote machine thats why you cannot use a restore or attach database function.

Solution:
For me the best thing to do is generate a script that will include the schema and the data of the database. This will serve as a script backup of your local database which can be run to any sql servers that you wanted. Sql Server 2008 already have the interface for this but for Sql Server 2005 you will need to have Sql Publishing Wizard.

You can download it from here: (remove spaces)

***http: //www.codeplex.com/sqlhost/Wiki /View.aspx?title=Database%20Publishing%20Wizard***

To create a script you can do this:

**Command to run which will create schema and database:**
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\Publishing\sqlpubwiz script -d AdventureWorks “C:\AdventureWorks.sql”

**Command to run which will create schema:**
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\Publishing\sqlpubwiz script -d AdventureWorks “C:\AdventureWorks.sql” -schemaonly

**Command to run which will create data:**
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\Publishing\sqlpubwiz script -d AdventureWorks “C:\AdventureWorks.sql” -dataonly

For more details please read...(Remove Spaces)

***http: //blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/11/16/ sql-server-2005-generate-script-with-data-from-database-database-publishing-wizard/***

This worked for me a lot of times.

Answer (score 0):

You will need access to the file system of the database server.
You have to detach the database from your local server and then copy the related .mdf and .ldf files to the target database server and then attach the files in the SQL server management studio of that database server.

Comment: but i dont have the access to the file system.

Comment: @Sumit Gupta - If you are able to access your local server from the management studio on that database server, then you can probably use Import/Export wizard to move all data from your local server to a new database on your DB server. Apart from this, I doubt moving your DB without file system access.