# Backup and restore from a network

Tags: sql-server

I can login to SQL Server installed on 'Machine A'. Now I need to `Backup` a database(say 'DB_A') of the 'Machine A' to my local disk, so that I can `Restore` the database to my machine's SQL Server. I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10371119/restore-database-in-sql-server-2005), but gets errors.

Comment: @marc_s  I think I can create a shared folder in my PC. Right ?

Comment: @marc_s Well. I could do it. If you answer this question with previous link, I will accept.

Comment: You can easily backup to a network and restore from your network destination automatically with the help of SqlBak. Here is a short explanation https://sqlbak.com/blog/sql-server-backup-and-restore-tutorial/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could do it. I did the following

1. Create a folder in your PC, say `MySharedDB`.
2. Set folder permissions as follows

   [image]
3. Then in Backup screen of SSMS add the UNC path `\\rauf\MySharedDB` to `Destination`

Answer (score 3):

You cannot directly do this.

SQL Server will only backup its data to **locally attached** drives on the server machine - or to a network UNC path that the SQL Server machine can access and has permissions to write to.

With that: of course, if you create a shared folder on your local machine, and have all the permissions setup correctly, then the SQL Server backup could write into that shared folder on your local machine. That would be the way to get a remote server's backup onto your local harddisk.

Answer (score 1):

As marc_s already said, SQL Server can only backup to local drives or to UNC paths.
If you do the backup with SQL Server Management Studio, you can **only** backup to local folders, nowhere else.
To backup to an UNC path, you need to do the backup via T-SQL:

- [Copy SQL Server Databases Remotely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7424015/copy-sql-server-databases-remotely/7424063#7424063)
- [How to copy a SQL Server 2005 database from local to the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133273/how-to-copy-a-sql-server-2005-database-from-local-to-the-server/4133726#4133726)

So you would need to create a shared folder on your machine, and do the backup from the server via T-SQL.
On the other hand - you don't need to create the shared folder on **your** machine. You can backup the server to **any** shared folder and restore from there.
Or you could create the backup locally on the server, make the backup folder on the server a shared folder, and restore the backup from there directly onto your machine.